# Why discriminate the base case allows me to complete the induction proof?

Tags: proof-techniques, coq

I have a successful completed proof which used induction. but I essentially proved the goal on the base case by tactic `discriminate`.  Why is this induction proof still stands?

the principle of induction tells us induction involves three steps:

```
     - show that the P(O) holds, (* O stands for the first item *);
     - show that, for any n, if P(n) holds, then so does
       P(next(n));
     - conclude that P(n) holds for all n.
```

but if I finished proving subgoal P(O) by discriminate, that is, confirmed the subgoal is impossible, how does that constitue as a holding base case?

Here's the proof in question:

```
Fixpoint filter {X:Type} (test: X->bool) (l:list X) : (list X) :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | h :: t =>
    if test h then h :: (filter test t)
    else filter test t
  end.

Theorem filter_property : forall (X : Type) (test : X -> bool) (x : X) (l lf : list X),     
filter test l = x :: lf -> test x = true.
Proof. 
induction l.
- intros. discriminate. 
- simpl. destruct (test x0) eqn:Etest. 
 + intros. injection H. intros. rewrite -> H1 in Etest. apply Etestx.
 + apply IHl.
Qed.
```

Comment: If you've proved the base case, you have a proof of the best case, no matter how you proved it… I think it's going to be hard to help you in vague terms like this. You should post the specific proof you don't understand.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' updated the proof text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that if the result of of `filter test l` is a non-empty list, then its first element passes `test`. You're using induction on `l`.

The base case for the induction is the empty list `[]`. For the base case, you need to prove that if `filter test [] = x :: lf` then `test x = true`. In order to prove this, you assume that `filter test [] = x :: lf`, and prove that this hypothesis is a contradiction. Indeed it is: there is no value of `x` and `lf` that makes `filter test [] = x :: lf` true, because `filter test []` is the empty list. So, for the base case, for any `x` and any `lf`, the proposition `filter test l = x :: lf -> test x = true` is true.

Using the notation you've used to state the principle of induction, P(n) has the form “Q(n) implies R(n)” (where Q(n) is “the result of filter is a non-empty list” and R(n) is “the first element passes the test”). It would be strange if *P(0)* was vacuously true, but that's not what's going on here: what's going on is that *R(0)* is vacuously true, because *Q(0)* is impossible. The base case *P(0)* is possible. It happens to have the form of an implication where the premise is impossible, but that's just happenstance.